# SQL-Exception in Java strange

Tags: java, db2, sqlexception

I have a program which is connected to a db2 z/os database. I get the following Exception:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSLH21E.5359534C564C3031, DRIVER=3.66.46
```

[this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21366855) one says my program is running out of statements. So I checked everything and summarised all sql-action:

```
Connection_1 
                Connection_2
        Resultset set1 = Connection_1.PreparedStatement(Select Table).open
        try {
            while (set1.next()) {
                Resultset set2 = Connection_1.PreparedStatement(find Dataset).open

                try{
                    if(set2.next()) {
                        Connection_2.PreparedStatement(Insert in Table).open
                        Connection_2.PreparedStatement(Insert in Table).close
                        Connection_2.PreparedStatement(update in Table).open
                        Connection_2.PreparedStatement(update in Table).close
                    }finally {
                        set2.close
                        PreparedStatemtn(find Dataset).close


                    }
                    if (something is true){
                        Connection_2.commit)()
                    }
                }
            }

            }finally{
                set1.close
                PreparedStatement(Select Table).close
                Connect_2.close
            }
```

Then in the moment just before my program chrash i create a lot of preparedStatements:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
                PreparedStatement statement = CONNECTION.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE");

            }
```

Then I get the following Error:

```
Exception stack trace:
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSLH219 0X5359534C564C3031, DRIVER=3.66.46
Concurrently open statements:
1. SQL string:  SELECT * FROM TABEL
   Number of statements:  10000
2. SQL string:  SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE
   Number of statements:  1
********************
```

So this looks like there is no problem with open Statements. Are there other possibilitys for an exception like this? Maybe I select to many datasets?

```
Resultset set1 = Connection_1.PreparedStatement(Select Table).open
```

This table got round about 4_000_000 datasets.

I hope someone can help me. If you need more information just tell me.

Kindly Regards!

Comment: SQL should execute statement one by one. Once the statement is excecuted and the result is returned then the task is closed. And then another statement has to be run.

Comment: OK. this mean I have to use different connections for set1 and set2?

Comment: yes you can try that out. Hence you are already have sets' ready. Just use them one by one. Instead of doing it together!

Comment: I still dont understand why this is a problem! Can you explain this to me? I got only two open statements at Connection_1. And this is too much?

Comment: Yes Technically what i understand so far is that it takes one statement per round. So when the statement starts the execution it will close the connection for the other statements until the current statement is not completely executed!

Comment: Do not create statements all at once; create them as you use them.